# Is it essential to use comma in a big number?

Tags: punctuation, commas, numbers, ielts, listening

Is it necessary to use comma in a big number? For example, if anyone writes `one million four hundred thousand and two` as 1400002 instead of 1,400,002 on answer sheet of listening section of IELTS test, will it be considered incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short, it is essential in English.

Comment: Essential to whom, in what context?

Comment: In academic writing it will depend on your style guide. I doubt you’d lose marks on a test for formatting a number a certain way, but I don’t know.

Comment: If the examiners advise you to write every nineteenth digit in green ink, it's best to go with their preferences. But this isn't a general English topic (and so is off-topic on ELU).

Comment: If you are discussing pure numbers, then the comma should be used. See: https://www.ieltsscore.com/ielts-writing-task-1-cycling-to-work-in-twelve-areas-in-uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for certain if this is an authoritative source, but the YouTube video ["[TIPS] IELTS Common Mistakes in Writing Numbers: Use Comma or Point ? (Part 3)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpqRHvWrbUs) suggests this:

Use a comma only when there are more than four digits. In other words:

> 2000 B.C.
> 10,000 B.C.

Per that, your answer should be 1,400,002.

But I'm assuming there are many IELTS-specific style guides that you could refer to which would answer the question definitively.

---

IELTS aside, the use of commas varies somewhat depending on what style is used, what country you're in, and the specific context of your writing. (Non-English languages can have completely different styles.)

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th. ed), 9.54:

> In a style followed in most general contexts in the United States and most other English-speaking parts of the world, for numerals of one thousand or more, commas are used between groups of three digits, counting from the right. Commas are *not* used for figures to the right of the decimal marker.
>
> 1,512
> 32,987
> 4,000,500
>
> *but*
>
> 0.32987
>
> Nor are commas used in page numbers, line numbers (e.g., in poetry and plays), addresses, and years (though years of five digits or more do include the comma).
>
> Punctuation conventions can be found on page 1535 of the tenth edition.
> Our business office is at 11030 South Langley Avenue.
> Human artifacts dating from between 35,000 BP and 5000 BP have been found there.
>
> In scientific writing, commas are often omitted from four-digit numbers.

However, in *Chicago*, 9.56:

> In the International System of Units (SI units), thin, fixed spaces rather than commas are normally used to mark off groups of three digits, both to the left and to the right of the decimal marker. (In electronic publications, a regular nonbreaking space may be used . . .) No space is used for groups of only four digits either to the left or to the right of the decimal marker (except in table columns that also include numbers having five or more digits, where it is needed for alignment). To mark the decimal, either a decimal point or a comma may be used, according to what is customary in a given context or region (the examples that follow show the decimal point).
>
> 3 426 869
> 0.000 007
> 2501.4865 (or 2 501.486 5)

Comment: 3 426 869 shows the thin fixed space style, contrast 3 426 869 with the regular spacing.

Comment: As there is currently no "thin space" on a keyboard, this is rather difficult to achieve.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's possible to use unicode character U+2009 as a thin space, but Stack Exchange only displays it as a regular space. Most other unicode characters in the standard range are displayed by this site, but not that one.

Comment: 3 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693  //v// 3 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 8693 426 869; @Jason Bassford (thin spaces, not necessarily U+2009, from Character Map)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've specifically converted the characters in the answer—but good luck telling the difference …

Comment: Much better. And next, we address the fact that commas are thinner in some fonts than in others.