# Comma or space in long numbers and the UK Standard Rule

Tags: british-english, numbers, rules

Is there a strict rule in the UK on how to write long figures?  If so, which one is it?

For example, if I need to write long numbers and follow the UK standard, which figure is correct?

> 10 000 000 000 people (ten billion people) or 10,000,000,000 people ?

Same example but with another figure: which one is correct?

> £1 000 000,85  or  £1,000,000.85

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it essential to use commas in a big number?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451219/is-it-essential-to-use-comma-in-a-big-number) where @Jason Bassford's well-researched answer states that even CMOS agrees that there are different conventions, none 'incorrect' and thus none 'the standard rule'. And people in the UK follow style guides just as those in the US do, possibly US-based style guides. As some in the US will follow UK-based style guides. _And advice given by different style guides often differs._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth It might be different in the US versus the UK.

Comment: @Naomi. There is no strict rule. We don't have a Style Czar any more than the people in the US do. Different people use different practices. I leave gaps (my degrees are in science, and this style is not science-only). // There are other threads addressing this: the use of the decimal point vs comma is dealt with elsewhere.

Comment: I'd add that in the UK << 10,000,000,000 people >> is probably still the more common format, (and I admit I've written a cheque thus styled)(**one** comma!), though the spaced variant is also used. _But the small rather than the large space is then the norm; I believe your spaced example isn't **correctly** spaced_.

Comment: In newspapers, magazines, etc, you are more likely to see a quantity such as 10 followed by 9 zeroes expressed in words as 'ten billion' or as e.g. '10bn'. Long numbers are unwieldy and open to misreading.

Comment: Edwin - you write nine-figure cheques? I'd _really_ like to be your friend.

Comment: I think it's worth saying explicitly that using a comma for the decimal is definitely wrong. All English-speaking locales use a decimal point. (For comparison, continental Europe uses a comma for the decimal point, and points to define thousands: UK 1,234.56→1.234,56 Eur)

Comment: @Michael Harvey I boldened the caveat. Do be sensible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not just a question about English and convention. There is also an associated issue of numerical precision and meaning. If I say that 945872321 face masks were counted out from a production line, I mean exactly that; if I say a billion people are over the age of 70, I mean that approximately 1000000000 people are of that age; a bank account holds a precise amount of money that should be expressed exactly even to the last penny or cent.

It follows that we should think first of the numerical aspect and only second of the way of writing. To write 1000000000 instead of writing a billion is in almost all cases unnecessary and misleading. The insertion of commas to improve readability is entirely a matter of taste but needs caution: you should be aware of the European convention that uses the comma for the decimal point!

Comment: This would be a useful and relevant comment (or two), but does not answer OP's actual question. _The answer being_ that most people in the UK, asked by someone to key in a billion in numerals, would give 1,000,000,000; some would give 1 000 000 000 (hopefully with half-space spaces rather than full-space spaces, but doubtful). Further, almost everyone would use a decimal point rather than a comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: 1 000 000 000 illustrates the thin fixed space style (ISU's preferred style) – contrast with  the normally spaced  1 000 000 000 (which ISU says will suffice).